# How to show xmal composite activity with complete design on workflow flow service xamlx file?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am developing some composite activity those consist of several code activities and WF framework activities.
When I drop it on workflow service (xmalx), it is viewed as a single activity. I want to show complete this custom activity with all child activities on workflow service.

Comment: If you're talking about dropping one workflow on another, and expecting to see that workflow in the design surface instead of the minimal activity designer... you can't.  That isn't supported.

Comment: Yes, You are right Will. is there any workaround to resolve this issue? is WF 4.5 resolved this issue?

Comment: @Vivek Unfortunately this is not available in the upcoming 4.5 release either.  Here is an article detailing what is though.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305677(v=vs.110)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to an MSDN post where a developer has a version of a custom activity designer that will do this.  You may have to make some modifications but I bet with a little effort you can get it to work for you.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/wfprerelease/thread/6bd297b8-23e4-402b-9e1b-56b816dacf42